# Socket Connection Weird Issue

Tags: android, sockets

I have an android app that uses socket connection. Im able to connect to two socket servers (one running on my local machine, the other running on a machine that i connect via internet using a fix IP). However when i try to connect to a socket server that its running on a computer connected to the same LAN im connected to, it doesn't work.

The strangest thing is that, if i run a ruby socket (client) and try to connect to the server that its on my local LAN with the SAME specifications (IP and Port) it works perfectly.

Anyone knows what could be happening?